# New Review system currently in beta testing

Tags: discussion, review

A new system for [reviewing posts that require moderation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review) is now live here at Web Applications.

For details, please see [the post on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta).

It's important to note that this is not (necessarily) a tool for Community Moderators. It's a tool to help the Community moderate itself. Please check it out and lend a hand.

If you have issues and questions, please post them on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review), not here. (Be sure to use the "review" tag as well.)

Comment: There will be changes to the `/review` page between now and when it's fully rolled out,